# I want to remove duplicates entry and combine the data

Tags: unix, awk

I have a CSV file containing the name of the gene in 1st column and their responding expression in the next column

**Example**

```
ABC1,Heart
ABC1,Brain
ABC1,Kidney
BRAC1,Heart
BRAC1,Lungs
RHO,Eye
RHO,Kidney
RPE65,Eye
```

**Required Output**

```
ABCA1,Heart;Brain;Kidney
BRAC1,Heart;Lungs
RHO,Eye;Kidney
RPE65,Eye
```

I want to separate them like this with any delimiter to show the expression

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368405/how-to-merge-duplicate-lines-into-one-line-separate-by-comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk

```
awk -F, ' { if($1==p) { printf(";%s",$2);next} printf("%s%s",NR==1? "" :"\n",$0);p=$1 } END { print "" } ' file
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat manoj.txt
ABC1,Heart
ABC1,Brain
ABC1,Kidney
BRAC1,Heart
BRAC1,Lungs
RHO,Eye
RHO,Kidney
RPE65,Eye
$ awk -F, ' { if($1==p) { printf(";%s",$2);next} printf("%s%s",NR==1? "" :"\n",$0);p=$1 } END { print "" } ' manoj.txt
ABC1,Heart;Brain;Kidney
BRAC1,Heart;Lungs
RHO,Eye;Kidney
RPE65,Eye
$
```

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner will do the "grouping":

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]?";":"")$2}
        END{for(x in a)print x FS a[x]}' file
```

if you want the output to be sorted, pipe the result to `sort`, like `awk....|sort`

Comment: These are obviously two lines! :P

Comment: Thanks, @kent but my  I'm not getting my desired output. my output looks like; Kidneyart
;LungsHeart
;Kidney
RPE65,Eye

Answer (score 1):

Another awk. This one relies on the data being sorted:

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "%s",($1==p?";"$2:ors $0);p=$1;ors=ORS}END{print ""}' <(sort -r file)
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F, '{                          # set separator
    printf "%s",($1==p?";"$2:ors $0)  # conditional output, depends on $1 changing
    p=$1                              # remember $1 for next round
    ors=ORS                           # lazy initialization for leading ORS removal
}
END { 
    print ""                          # cleanup the last output
}' <(sort file)
```

Output:

```
ABC1,Brain;Heart;Kidney
BRAC1,Heart;Lungs
RHO,Eye;Kidney
RPE65,Eye
```

Comment: Thanks, @james but my I'm not getting my desired output. my output looks like; Kidneyart ;LungsHeart ;Kidney RPE65,Eye

Comment: Probably Windows line ending. Try: `awk -F, -v RS="\r\n" ...`

Comment: @ManojkumarK The same probably works with all the other awk solutions here.

Comment: I don't know how it worked i saved my file from csv to txt it works automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s",$1==l?";"$2:(FNR != 1)?RS $0:$0;l=$1}END{print ""}' file
```

**Output**

```
ABC1,Heart;Brain;Kidney
BRAC1,Heart;Lungs
RHO,Eye;Kidney
RPE65,Eye
```

<sub>**Note:** Assumes sorted input</sub>

Comment: Thanks, @sjsam, but I'm not getting the output as you showed. my output looks like; Kidneyart ;LungsHeart ;Kidney RPE65,Eye

Comment: @ManojkumarK Is the file input format exactly same as you mentioned ? If so what is the source of file? I remommend doing a `dos2unix file` if the file came from a non-unix environment.

Comment: Ya, it's the same format as I have mentioned, but my file is in CSV format. if I change my CSV into txt file I'm getting my desired results